# Batch /a doesn't store a value

Tags: variables, batch-file, scripting

Code:

```
@echo off
set /a x=5
set /a TNUM=%x%-3
echo %TNUM%
pause
```

And the output is:

```
ECHO is off
```

So, how do I fix this?

Here's the full code:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions
set /a COLUMNS=60
set /a ROWS=40
mode con: cols=%COLUMNS% lines=%ROWS%

:main
    set /a xpos=5
    set /a ypos=5

    call:displayScreen

    pause >nul
    goto :eof

::FUNCTIONS::
:displayScreen
    set /a TEMPR=%ROWS%-3
    for /l %%c in (1,1,%COLUMNS%) do echo|set /p=#
    for /l %%r in (1,1,%TEMPR%) do (
        echo|set /p=#
        if %%r==%ypos% (
            set /a TNUM=%xpos%-3
            echo %TNUM%
            for /l %%t in (1,1,%TNUM%) do echo|set /p=A
            echo|set /p=o
            set /a TNUM=%COLUMNS%-%xpos%-1
            for /l %%t in (1,1,%TNUM%) do echo|set /p=A
        ) else (
            set /a TNUM=%COLUMNS%-2
            for /l %%t in (1,1,%TNUM%) do (
                echo|set /p=A
            )
        )
        echo|set /p=#
        echo.
    )
    for /l %%c in (1,1,%COLUMNS%) do echo|set /p=#
```

The main problem is in the display screen function. It is supposed to print the screen and have the x at the two coordinates I gave it. I put in echo %TNUM% so I could see what was in it, and it always amounts to "".

Comment: Have you tried adding `setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION`?  Then replace `%x%` with `!x!`?

Comment: I'm just learning batch, so I don't know much. How would I fit that I to the code? Do you mind editing it so I can see?

Comment: Works perfectly happily for me. Are you posting by cutting-and-pasting?

Comment: +1 Your code works fine.  Always show what you are actually doing because if you don't then you will get answers that probably won't work in the actual task.

Comment: @foxidrive I added the full code.

Comment: @Magoo I added the full code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are mainly three ways to obtain the indicated behaviour

**1** - Problems with variable expansion. In batch files, lines or blocks of lines (a set of lines enclosed in parenthesis), are parsed, executed and then the operation is repeated on the next line/block.

During the parse phase all read operations on variables (any `%var%`) are removed from code, replacing them with the value stored in the variable **before** starting to execute the line/block of code.

So, if inside the line/block the value of a variable is changed, this value can not be readed/retrieved inside the same line/block during execution phase. Why? Because there are no read operations in the line/block to retrieve the value of the variable. This code

```
set x=0
if 1==1 (
    set x=1
    set y=%x%
)
echo x=%x% y=%y%
```

will echo to console `x=1 y=0` Why? When the `if` block of code is parsed (the full block), the read operations (`=%x%`) where replaced at parse time with the values inside the variables at parse time and the code executed is

```
if 1==1 (
    set x=1
    set y=0  <- Read operation in x replaced with its value at parse time
)
```

that is, the changed value stored in x can not be retrieved.

This case is usually solved with the usage of delayed expansion. It is a behaviour that can be activated with command `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` and that allow the programmer to change, *where needed*, the syntax to access variable content from `%var%` to `!var!`, indicating to the parser that the expansion of the variable (the replacement of the read operation with the value of the variable) must be delayed until the execution phase. In the proposed sample it should be

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion   <- delayed expansion enabled
set x=0
if 1==1 (
    set x=1
    set y=!x!  <- Read operation delayed
)
echo x=%x% y=%y%
```

**2** - Spaces. An habitual problem with variable declaration is

```
set /a TNUM = %x%-3
           ^.......This value is included in the variable name
```

The space is included in the variable name, and echoing `%TNUM%` fails as this is not the name of the variable, it is named `%TNUM %`.

**BUT** as i forgot and @jeb corrects in comments, while `set` and `set /p` exhibit this behaviour, this will NOT happen when `set /a` is used. In this case a parser with different rules is used (for example, it allows variables references without previous expansion) and the indicated space will be supressed.

**3** - You machine has extensions disabled by default. If extensions are disabled, `set /a` will not work and no value will be assigned to the variable

```
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions
    set /a x=5
    set /a TNUM=x-3
    echo %TNUM%
```

**Summarizing**, to execute the line `echo %TNUM%` and obtain the indicated `ECHO is off` it is necessary that when the line is parsed `TNUM` is not defined or it only contain spaces or tabs.

As, a priori, when the line `set /a TNUM=%x%-3` is executed, a value is assigned to the variable (at least the `-3`), it seems your problem is the case 1 (the echoed value was replaced before the execution) or the case 3 (you have no value to echo as the `set` operation failed).

**edited** With all the code posted, the problem is delayed expansion.

```
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
    set /a COLUMNS=60
    set /a ROWS=40
    mode con: cols=%COLUMNS% lines=%ROWS%

:main
    set /a xpos=5
    set /a ypos=5

    call :displayScreen

    pause >nul
    goto :eof

::FUNCTIONS::
:displayScreen
    set /a TEMPR=%ROWS%-3
    for /l %%c in (1,1,%COLUMNS%) do echo|set /p=#
    for /l %%r in (1,1,%TEMPR%) do (
        echo|set /p=#
        if %%r==%ypos% (
            set /a TNUM=%xpos%-3
            for /l %%t in (1,1,!TNUM!) do echo|set /p=A
            echo|set /p=o
            set /a TNUM=%COLUMNS%-%xpos%
            for /l %%t in (1,1,!TNUM!) do echo|set /p=A
        ) else (
            set /a TNUM=%COLUMNS%-2
            for /l %%t in (1,1,!TNUM!) do (
                echo|set /p=A
            )
        )
        echo|set /p=#
    )
    for /l %%c in (1,1,%COLUMNS%) do echo|set /p=#
```

Comment: The space problem is not present when the `/a` option is used, only without options or `/p` is used

Comment: I added the full code and did the setlocal enableextentions. I'm probably doings something horribly wrong. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: @Twonty2, Your problem is delayed expansion. See point number 1

Comment: I know you are right MC ND but reading your first paragraph gives me a headache. ;)  I find it hard to follow the words.

Comment: @foxidrive, when i wrote the paragrah i thought that the problem was not delayed expansion so i ran over it. My fault. Now changed. Hope you feel better ;-)

Comment: @MCND Okay, so this works when I call TNUM with the '!' around the variable. But why do I call !TNUM! like this, but %xpos% like this?

Comment: @Twonty2, you only **need** delayed expansion if the value you are trying to retrieve has been changed inside the same block where you are trying to read. `xpos` is defined out of the block (`for /l %%r`) and its value does not change inside the block, so, there is no need to use delayed expansion. BUT `TNUM` is changed *inside* the block and this changed value needs to be retrieved inside this same block, so, delayed expansion is needed. Anyway, you can use `!xpos!` and it will also work. I was just trying to show how the *"where needed"* works.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it isn't waiting to evaluate `%x%`.  So you can add `ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION` so that it will wait to evaluate `x` so that it will be initialized during the math operation.

```
@echo off
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set /a x=5
set /a TNUM=!x!-3
echo !TNUM!
endlocal
pause
```

Comment: Oh okay. That makes sense. I'll try it out a bit later, thank you!

Comment: This is correct in your full code above though the `!x!` can just be the plain variable name `x` in a set /a command - did you implement this answer?  You can leave `endlocal` out too unless you really need to nuke the variables.

Answer (score 0):

Within a block statement `(a parenthesised series of statements)`, the **entire** block is parsed and **then** executed. Any `%var%` within the block will be replaced by that variable's value **at the time the block is parsed** - before the block is executed.

Since the `for...%%r...` loop executes a block of code (from the `(` following the `do` through to the matching `)` ) then any `%tnum%` appearing within that block will be replaced by the value of `tnum` **when the loop was parsed**. `Tnum` has no value when the block is started, so that's what is shown.

`tnum` is being set within the loop, so since you have `enabledelayedexpansion` set to ON in the `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` statement at the start of the program, you need to use **!tnum!** in place of **%tnum%** within the loop to access the value of `tnum` as it changes.